# How do I retrieve a git repository from Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I created an app and deployed it to Heroku, but I didn't have a github git repo (I know really bad idea!) and my local git repo has been deleted (just plain stupidity here).  So I have no copies of my source.  I need to make some updates and the only thing I can think of is doing a checkout from Heroku.

Is there a way to do a checkout from Heroku?  Is there a way I can retrieve the source from the Heroku git repo?

Comment: Heroku can serve as your main external Git repository. It's not a "really bad idea" to not push to Github as well.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You just need clone you git repo link by your heroku app.

```
git clone git@heroku.com:<YOUR_APP>.git
```

Comment: I wish I could add an upvote but I need rep of 15 or more to do that and sadly I only have 14.  I don't know how to accept as a good answer but I will gladly do it if you tell me how.

Comment: @luis: click empty checkmark below answer's score. Thus you'll mark answer as correct.

Comment: @shingara:  I have done both now. Upvoted and Accepted as good answer!  Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

In 2014, you could do

```
heroku git:clone -a <your-app-name>
```

[Documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app)